# Error parsing array of strings to JSON ARRAY column in Snowflake

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an SQL column in my Snowflake table declared as the `ARRAY` data type. I tried doing a COPY INTO from a CSV where one row contained a value for this column of `["A","B"]`. However, this returned the following error:

> Error parsing JSON: "[""A"",""B""]"

This seems to me to indicate that Snowflake doesn't accept an array of strings as valid JSON. However, I'm getting mixed results when testing this in the Snowflake console:

```
CALL CHECK_JSON('["A", "B"]') # Returns null

CALL CHECK_JSON("[""A"",""B""]") # Returns error
```

How should I format this data to deal with this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, I tried using the `ARRAY_CONSTRUCT` on the column in my `COPY INTO` statement to fix the issue. However, the CSV column was being treated as a single string, so it was producing an array with a single item. So, what I actually had to do was this:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL(my_col, $$[^\"\\[\\],]+$$)
```

This worked when I tested the query but Snowflake does not allow the `REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL` function in `COPY` statements. So, I actually had to do this:

```
SPLIT(TRIM(REPLACE(my_col, '"', ''), '[]'), ',')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSON:

["A", "B"] <-- This is a valid JSON

"[""A"",""B""]" <-- This is not a valid JSON:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
"[""A"",""B""]"
---^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'STRING'
```